# Does using CodeIgniter's XSS filtering avoid the need to escape when outputting?

Tags: codeigniter, xss

CodeIgniter provides a couple of convenient APIs for XSS filtering.

- 'global_xss_filtering' in config.php.
- 'xss_clean' rule for individual fields, when using the form validation library.

If you use this feature, does it avoid the need to escape fields when outputting them?

Answer (score 4):

There are some situations where xss_clean will not protect you.  [Issue 470](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/470#issuecomment-2156667) includes this example:

```
public function index()
{

    $name = $this->security->xss_clean('hover me" onmouseover=alert("XSS2") "'); 
    echo '</div>Name:<input value="'.$name.'">';
    echo '</body></html>';
}
```

The response from developers was that this is by design, and to suggest that `$name` should have been escaped using `form_prep()`.

If you use `set_value('field-name', 'default')` in order to preserve user input when a form fails validation), that will ... attempt to call form_prep() for you.  The caveat is that if you don't have the form validation library loaded, it won't escape the 'default' parameter.  ([Issue 1781](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/1781), fixed in 3.0-dev).

If you *are* running the current 3.0-dev, then `form_prep()` is more specific about which characters it escapes.  It should avoid XSS either way; it just has unexpected results in some situations.  E.g. if you try to enter a literal "`&amp;`" in 3.0-dev, and then the form fails validation, the field value will change to `&` without warning.  This change was an attempt to work around problems with double-escaping ([issue 1953](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/1953)).